# How to reclaim rights for the profile folder after changing the username in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, user-controls

I recently changed my username in Windows 10 and I just discovered that all folders and files in my profile folder are now write-protected. I also can't remove the write-protection.

The profile folder is still named by the older username. Is there a way to fix this or do I have to change my username back?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, had that user password or some kind of key? create a live usb with Hiren's boot, open NT Password and you can solve it, there are times that usually happens and with that tool, in the cases that have happened to me, it has worked.
Regards
PD: Download it from here, you will have to save it on a USB, also you have the steps: https://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/

Comment: Well, it is the same user and password. I just changed the username. Is it not possible to change this from within Windows?

Comment: You can, try with what he says in this video, the system is windows7, but it is practically the same: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZnwfagQj98

Comment: I happen to understand Spanish a bit, but it doesn't work :)